# How can i wait till i receive all the tcp packets to Client from Server using NSStream

Tags: ios, json, tcp, bonjour, nsstream

```
 case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
            BBLogMsg("End Encountered")
            guard let inputStream = self.inputStream else {
                return BBLogError("no input stream")
            }

            let bufferSize     = 4096
            var buffer         = Array<UInt8>(count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
            var message        = ""

            while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
                let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
                if len < 0 {
                    BBLogError("error reading stream...")
                    return self.closeStreams()
                }
                if len > 0 {
                    message += NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: len, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
                }
                if len == 0 {
                    BBLogError("no more bytes available...")
                    break
                }
            }

            responseString += message
            self.resolveReseponse()

            self.closeStreams()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
public func resolveReseponse() {

    guard let data = responseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
        return BBLogMsg("Server get disorted data")
    }
    do {

        guard let _ = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {

            return BBLogMsg("\n\n\n\nClient response string errorn\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        }

        self.didReceivedDataCallback?(responseString)
        responseString = ""
    }
    catch
    {
        BBLogMsg("JSON Error Parser Issue \(responseString)")
    }
}
```

What i did: If Server sent any data to client then client is directly validating json. if client got any corrupt json,then client is adding next packet data and validating.

What i need: Client should wait till it get all the data and do validation json data which i got from server

Answer (score 0):

This is not in swift, but i think the approach would be the same...

I'm currently using this:

```
if (stream == inputStream)
{
    uint8_t buffer[1024];

    int len = 0;

    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
    {
        len = (int)[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];

        if (len > 0)
        {
            [output appendString: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        }
    }
    if (output.length > 0)
    {
        [self socketValidateResponse:output];
    }
}
```

This is using `NSMutableString` and just appending chunked data.

Inside `-socketValidateResponse` I have this to validate...

```
- (void)socketValidateResponse:(NSString *)stringResponse
{
    stringResponse = stringResponse == nil ? @"" : stringResponse;

    id socketJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[stringResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                      error:nil];

    BOOL isSupported = YES;

    NSLog(@"Socket Log: -> \"%@\"", stringResponse);

    if ([socketJson isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Response is of class NSArray");
    }
    else if ([socketJson isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Response is of class NSDictionary");
    }
    else //add more kind of class if necessary
    {
        isSupported = NO;

        NSLog(@"Response is of class %@ not supported", [stringResponse class]);
    }

    if (isSupported)
        //[self.delegate YJSocket:self didReceiveResponse:isSupported ? socketJson : nil];
}
```

Hope this would help.. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hey @0yeoj my case is : i am getting two 2000 bytes packets. what i am doing : i am directly validating first packet and validating second packet. What my goal is: Client should wait till all the packets receive. After that it should de serialize the data which i got from server